# Trying to run cucumber tests in jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my cucumber tests in my (local) Jenkins:

```
/Users/kris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/rake --rakefile android/rakefile
(in /)
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- cucumber
```

My rakefile looks like the following:

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.profile = 'ci'
end

task :default => :features
```

I'm just trying to set up a really basic run, it looks like I need to either set up a plugin for cucumber (which I thought I had done) - or set some variable to make cucumber available to Jenkins.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: The error "cannot load such file -- cucumber" says that it can't find cucumber installed. Check via your Jenkins job if cucumber is installed as a gem (use gem list). If you are using bundler, run "bundle install" before running your rake, that might show you the cause for failure. Its possible that cucumber is installed as a gem on your machine for default ruby, but not for ruby-1.9.3-p545 / Jenkins user (that you are using with rvm)